# JS - functions do not called in fetch-then promise case if the fetch was a post

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am still learning ES6. I have two classes.

**FetcherClass**:

```
static getModalRequest() {
    return fetch(FetcherClass.getNewLink, {
        method: 'GET'
    });

}

static postModalRequest() {
    return fetch(FetcherClass.getPostLink, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: FetcherClass.getFormData('rating-request-form')
    });

}
```

The first function is a Get method and second is a Post method to fetch data from the server side.

This is the part of the modal class:

```
addMainTemplate() {
    FetcherClass.getModalRequest().then(html => {
           // This is fired here always.
        this.renderHTMLTemplate(html.text());
    });
   }

sendRequest() {
        FetcherClass.postModalRequest().then(html =>
            // This function is never fired in the postModalRequest
            this.renderHTMLTemplate(html.text())
        );
   }
```

When I call the `addMainTemmplate` function it always fire the `renderHTMLTemplate` function! So when the **Fetch promise is a GET it works**.

But if the Fetch promise is a POST, then it not works. The `SendREquest` function - in the "then" case - never fires the `renderHTMLTemplate`.

But I do not know the real reason, maybe because of the GET and POST HTTP method?

Yes, **I get the result from the Server in both cases, because in Developer Mode of Firefox** I see the response status equals 200 and I see the HTML templates (they are not the same html, so I can see).
In the Console tab of Firefox I do not see any errors!

Update:

```
sendRequest() {
        FetcherClass.postModalRequest().then(html =>

            console.log("before"); 
            // there is a console.log("inside"); but it never called.
            this.renderHTMLTemplate(html.text())
            console.log("after");
        );
   }
renderHTMLTemplate(html) {
    console.log("inside");
}
```

In this case I can see the "before" and the "after". but the "inside" is not in the console.

Comment: Sounds like there was an error, even if it wasn't obvious. Try adding a `.catch` after the `.then` to see what it was (or, to see if catch block is entered into at all)

Comment: What does `FetcherClass.getFormData('rating-request-form')` return?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, nothing in the .catch case. As I wrote, the server perfectly gave back the html ;)

Comment: @guest271314 it returns `new FormData(document.getElementById(elementId));` where the elementId equals `rating-request-form` id

Comment: Interesting, mind posting a link to where you're posting to (dummied-up if you want) so we can see the behavior for ourselves and try to figure it out?

Comment: Can you include the complete HTML and JavaScript at the question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added the "update" section. I cannot updaet here, because Stackoverflow says, it contains too many source code.

So the wired thing, in the then, the console.log() run...

Comment: What does `console.log(html)` print? Why do you expect the response from server to have a `text` method?

Comment: Note that `fetch(...).then` gives you a Response object, not actual HTML. If the response is OK, you can call `.text()` on it, which will return *another* `Promise` which resolves to the text. Still, that doesn't sound relevant for the behavior you're describing - are you sure this is the code, verbatim, or did you remove parts of it to simplify? (those removed parts may be essential to figuring out the issue)

Answer (score 1):

The code calls [`Body.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) though does not use `async/await`. `Body.text()` returns a `Promise`.

`html` within `renderHTMLTemplate` is a `Promise` object, not plain text.

```
static getModalRequest() {
    return fetch(FetcherClass.getNewLink, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .catch(e => { throw e })    
}

static postModalRequest() {
    return fetch(FetcherClass.getPostLink, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: FetcherClass.getFormData('rating-request-form')
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .catch(e => { throw e })
}
```

Handle `throw`n error

```
FetcherClass.postModalRequest()
.then(html =>
   console.log(html); 
   this.renderHTMLTemplate(html)
)
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a view of what happens, add a handler on the error case :

```
FetcherClass.postModalRequest().then(
    html => this.renderHTMLTemplate(html.text()),
    // the second handler is called if promise "fails" (is rejected)
    function() { console.log(arguments); }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that my fetch was called from a `onSubmit` handler. This meant as soon as the `fetch` fired the request the form was submitted and the page reloaded. To stop this add an `event.preventDefault();`.

```
submitForm(e) {

    fetch('/api/' + url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(...)
    .catch(error => {
        throw new Error(error)
    });

    // Add this to stop the form submitting and the page reloading
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this.renderHTMLTemplate(html.text())` with `html.text().then(this.renderHTMLTemplate)`

The function `html.text()` doesn't return your html text, actually it returns a promise which then it will be resolved to your html text value.